# My mongoose populate() function isnt working, I dont know why

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to populate the `content` key of my `posts` model with the contents of my `content` collection but it isnt working. The `content` collection is getting populated but the data isnt getting passed to `posts` collection's `content` key.

### Schemas:

```
    const postsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      _id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      content: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Content' }]
    
    })
    const contentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      _id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      subHeading: String,
      subHeadingContent: String,
      image: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentTyle: String
      }
    })
    const content = mongoose.model("Content", contentSchema)
    const posts = mongoose.model("Posts", postsSchema)
```

### Post request to populate the collections:

```
// Write a new post
app.post("/create", function (req, res) {
  let Posts = {
    title: req.body.newTitle,
    subheading: req.body.newSubHeading,
    subheadingcontent: req.body.newSubHeadingContent
  }
  postsArray = [];
  postsArray.push(Posts)
  console.log(postsArray);
  postsArray.forEach((post) => {
    content.create({
      _id: uuidv4(),
      subHeading: post.subheading,
      subHeadingContent: post.subheadingcontent
    })
    posts.create({
      _id: uuidv4(),
      title: post.title,
    })
    posts.find().populate('content').exec((err, posts) => console.log("populated: ", posts))
  })

  res.redirect("/overview");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have a postsArray & a for loop since your only trying to create a post from a single object.

Anyways, the reason it's not showing up is because you need to push the content object to your posts array.
First, you give a variable to the `content.create`,
then you push the variable to the array when you're creating the post

```
app.post("/create", function (req, res) {
    let post = {
        title: req.body.newTitle,
        subheading: req.body.newSubHeading,
        subheadingcontent: req.body.newSubHeadingContent
    }

    const postContent = content.create({
        _id: uuidv4(),
        subHeading: post.subheading,
        subHeadingContent: post.subheadingcontent
    })

    posts.create({
        _id: uuidv4(),
        title: post.title,
        { $push: { content: postContent } }
    })

    posts.find().populate('content').exec((err, posts) => console.log("populated: ", posts))
    res.redirect("/overview");
})
```